# Что такое атрибуты в Lua 5.4?

Tags: lua, атрибуты

*Lua 5.4*
[добавляет](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/#changes)
два *атрибута* при объявлении локальных переменных:
`const` и `close`. Для чего они и как их
использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Атрибуты указываются в угловых скобках после названия переменной.

Атрибут 
[`const`](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#3.3.7)
позволяет объявить константу: попытка присвоить переменной новое
значение приведёт к ошибке:

```lua
local a <const> = 42
a = 100500
```

```
lua: tmp.lua:2: attempt to assign to const variable 'a'
```

Атрибут `close` используется для создания
“[подлежащих закрытию](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#3.3.8)”
переменных. При выходе за пределы текущей области действия или
возникновении ошибки, у этих объектов вызовется метаметод
`__close`:

```lua
local mt = {
  __close = function(file, error)
    print("file " .. file.name .. " is closed")
  end,
}

function open(filename)
  print("file " .. filename .. " opened")

  local file = { name = filename, }
  setmetatable(file, mt)

  return file
end

do
  local list <close> = open("list.txt")

  -- …

  do
    local index <close> = open("index.txt")

    -- …
  end
end
```

```
file list.txt opened
file index.txt opened
file index.txt is closed
file list.txt is closed
```

Метаметод `__close` должен присутствовать у объекта на момент
объявления подлежащей закрытию переменной.

В стандартной библиотеке можно отметить этим методом обладают
обработчики файлов
([*file handles*](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#6.8)),
возвращаемые `io.open`.

Comment: Ещё упустили несколько важных моментов про `__close`: во-первых, он местами поддерживается стандартной библиотекой, вроде файловых дескрипторов. Во-вторых, `__close` обязан присутствовать на момент присвоения значения переменной (как понял из списка рассылки), либо переменной нужно присвоить `nil`.

Comment: @val Добавил, спасибо.